# How to share c# source between Unity projects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We have two projects underway and want to share some classes between them. The shared source must be in a single location so when a programmer on Project1 updates the code those changes are immediately seen in Project2.

The important part is that we do not want to maintain multiple copies of the same code. i think we would agree that its simply bad practise to do so.

The only option appears to be putting the code in a class library and load it as a plugin into each project. But I don't believe this works when referencing Unity types like GameObject or transform.

In C/C++ land we could put the source in a directory and include it into any solution we wanted - doesn't seem to be so easy in Unity-land. Is their a better way to share code between unity projects?

**EDIT:** All projects, including the shared code, are already under source control. This is not a Source Control question, its a framework issue. (And obviously I need to write better questions!)

Lets say the directory structure looks like this...

C:\
  Project1\
    Assets\
      CodeForProject1\
      StandardAssets\
    Library\

C:\
  Project2\
    Assets\
      CodeForProject2\
      Resources\
    Library\

D:\
  UsefulCode\
    PlayerClass\
    WeaponsClass\
    DataAccessClass\

Can Unity reference code from other projects? Can Unity reference code outside of its own Assets folder? If so, how?

Comment: *"But I don't believe this works when referencing Unity types like GameObject or transform."* What makes you belive that? Your own Dll's can reference `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll` too.

Comment: While I am very interested to see a solution for this, I'd like to mention two ways to work around this problem. (1) git and submodule for subfolders inside, and (2) it is possible to have soft link to folders outside Untiy projects. Unity will recognise the soft-linked folders as parts of their assets and build project accordingly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to develop shared code for a Unity project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596022/how-to-develop-shared-code-for-a-unity-project)

Comment: We are using SVN external in our projects and are very happy with it. Updating code in with one project and getting it in the other project takes me 3 clicks and ideally writing 1 commit message about the change (yeah documentation!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand exactly what you're facing, we faced the same problem here some time ago.

The idea of our shared code is to be sort of a middleware, so it is natural that it will evolve through. Our solution was to create a git module for the shared code. I know you said that it's not a source control question, but at least here in my company, create a dll was not a good solution since we are changing the shared code constantly (we tried soft-links too, but it was very painful to maintain in all machines).

Here we created two projects: one for the middleware and another just for the tests. The last one have only the gitmodule to the middleware and a bunch of unit tests. We did it to ensure that there is no dependency to other projects. Both are in the source control. So when someone wants to implement a new feature inside the middleware, he/she make it inside the tests project, and when it's done commits to both projects.

Oh! And you *can* make a dll with Unity types and use them normally.

Comment: We used directory symlinks (`mklink /d ...`) to include external folders into our Assets/Plugins folder and found it to be working quite well. We used a batch script to set it up. Come to think of it: you could even make the Editor call that script for you automatically if it detects the symlink to be missing.

Comment: Your solution is interesting, but we can not implement it because our projects are already part of a single GIT repository and it is impossible to insert a repository inside another.

Comment: Well, it's possible to insert a git repo inside another. [Submodules](https://gist.github.com/gitaarik/8735255) are exactly that! I confess they can be sometimes overwhelmingly confusing, but they worth the extra work involved IMHO. I advise using a [git gui client](https://git-scm.com/download/gui/windows) like [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) or [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) to handle submodules (at least at the begining).